# How to install GNOME Control Center?

Tags: gnome-control-center, gnome-color-manager

In Ubuntu I installed 'GNOME Color Manager'. According to Ubuntu this software is supposed to be used with 'GNOME Control Center'. But I can't find 'GNOME Control Center' anywhere. Has it ceased to exist?
My real problem is that I want to color calibrate my HP printer. But to do that, I need to print out a color calibration sheet without any profile enabled and later I need to import and enable a newly created ICC profile.
According to the printer calibration service, printing of the sheet, without any ICC profile enabled, can be done with GIMP. But that seems like 'shooting sparrows with cannons'...

Comment: It's the"settings"application.

Comment: Yes, it must be so: I tried to install 'GNOME Control Center' with "sudo apt install gnome-control-center", but it is already installed.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I didn't know about this package, I thought `gnome-control-center` is tweak tool. But it looks like they're different packages (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center). Although I'm not sure whether installing this would solve Henrik R.'s issue, may be he can confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what do you mean, if you mean "gnome tweaks" use this command 
`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`
 otherwise, i guess you mean the default control center of the system itself, that's gnome control center